# OpenLayers - What exactly is the "document" element

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I use the function `document.getElementById('...')` but I don't get what exactly 'document' is ! I try to search where my bug is, I have a big problem in placing two types of markers (with 2 different GeoJSON files) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document` is the webpage content. You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp). `document.getElementById` let you access a particular element (a `div` or else) so you can modify its content.

In the context of OpenLayers, one would typically use it to display information in a `div` that is either overlaid over the map, or elsewhere in the page.